# Hiding settargetObjectId while sending email..?

Tags: apex, email-template, singleemailmessage

Hi I have used contact as settargetObjectId and whenever an email is sent this contact emailid  also get copied in the email list..

Is there any way to put this contact emailid(settargetObjectId ) in bcc list so it is always hidden from the recepient.

Also please note i am using template to send out email notifications..

Please help...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this.

`setTargetObjectId(id)` is used to send email to Lead, Contact or User. It is defined for main email recipient (same as toAddress(String[]) when using template. It will always in `"To:"`

Comment: so there is no way to bypass this thing..??

Comment: When sending email using template `setTargetObjectId(id)` is required. In that case `setTargetObjectId(id)` replaces `setToAddress(String[] addr)`. So there is no way to bypass if using template. @miku

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, which consists of creating a temporary dummy contact on the fly, is described here:
https://techman97.wordpress.com/tag/settargetobjectid/

This way you can at least prevent from sending to an additional email address. It will however show an extra recipient in the *to:*  line.

In order to send a bcc, use the setBccAddresses method:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setBccAddresses

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the email template you have to use `setTargetObjectId(id)`. However if at the same time you set the `setToAddresses('someemail@example.com)` it will override the `setTargetObjectId(id)` value. Thus no email will be sent to the `setTargetObjectId(id)`. I just did this several hours ago.